# Intent data not displaying right

Tags: android

I'm having a issue where when I go to the next activity and pass then data with the intent it is only showing me the last entry off the DB and not the clicked items info.

.java

```
public class TimsFavs extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

// Database results
String col0,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timsfavs);
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    //---get all Locations---
    db.open();

    Cursor c =  db.getAllLocation();

    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {

            col0 =  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID));
            col1 =  c.getString(1);
            col2 =  c.getString(2);
            col3 =  c.getString(3);
            col4 =  c.getString(4);
            col5 =  c.getString(5);
            col6 =  c.getString(6);
            col7 =  c.getString(7);

            results.add(col0);

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));
    ListView lv;
    lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(83, 05, 14));
    lv.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) this);

}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> TimsFavs, View view, int position, long id) {

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimsFavsMore.class);

    i.putExtra("ct_id_pass", col0);
    i.putExtra("ct_storeid_pass", col1);
    i.putExtra("ct_address_pass", col2);
    i.putExtra("ct_city_pass", col3);
    i.putExtra("ct_province_pass", col4);
    i.putExtra("ct_country_pass", col5);
    i.putExtra("ct_pcode_pass", col6);
    i.putExtra("ct_phnum_pass", col7);

    startActivity(i);
    finish();

}
```

}

and my other activity is

`public class TimsFavsMore extends Activity {
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

```
String rowId;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.timsfavsmore);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle b = i.getExtras();

         final String rowId = b.getString("ct_id_pass");
         final String phnum = b.getString("ct_phnum_pass");
         final String storeid = b.getString("ct_storeid_pass");
         final String address = b.getString("ct_address_pass");
         final String city = b.getString("ct_city_pass");
         final String province = b.getString("ct_province_pass");
         final String country = b.getString("ct_country_pass");
         final String pcode = b.getString("ct_pcode_pass");

        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        title.setText(Html.fromHtml("<br>Row ID: " + rowId + "<br><b><u>Location Address:</u></b><br><br>Store #" + storeid + "<br><br>" + address + "<br>" + city + ", " + province + "<br>" + country +"<br>" + pcode +"<br><br><b><u>Contact Info:</b></u><br><br>" + phnum +"<br>"));

// open to Nav

final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gohere);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String uri = "google.navigation:q=Tim%20Hortons,%20" + address + ",%20" + city + ",%20" + province + ",%20" + pcode + "";
        Intent i2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivity(i2);

    }
});

// open to maps

final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showmap);
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String uri2 = "geo:0,0?q=Tim%20Hortons,%20" + address + ",%20" + city + ",%20" + province + ",%20" + pcode + "";
        Intent i3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri2));
        startActivity(i3);

    }
});

// Add to My Timmies List

final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.removefav);
button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

      //---add 2 SQLite---

        db.open();

        if (db.deleteLocation(rowId))
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Delete successful.", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Delete failed.", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
        db.close();

       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyTimmies.class);
       startActivity(i);
       finish();

    }
});


final Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.favsdone);
button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

   Intent i4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyTimmies.class);
       startActivity(i4);
       finish();

    }
});
 }
```

}`

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating through your cursor and assigning the values to your strings.  when it completes the iteration, your strings only contain the last value you assigned and then you pass that.

You should bind your list to a SimpleCursorAdapter instead of creating a whole different string array.  Then in your onClickListener, you can just pass the key that identifies your row of data in the database.

Comment: yes your right now i just have to figure out the coding for it thanks for the direction to take.

Comment: look at the notepad sample - it has a simple list view that binds to a cursor and should provide a good launching point for you. http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fresources%2Ftutorials%2Fnotepad%2F&rct=j&q=android%20notepad%20example&ei=wEeiTfOgB5T2gAfz8tnaBQ&usg=AFQjCNGqDN3kFwMcsPBsIQbCFK69WM1cQg&cad=rja

Comment: i have looked and notepad and cant make heads or tails of it.